# Iterating through all the members of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, iteration

I have two `struct`s defined as in the following:

```
struct vertex
{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

struct finalVertex
{
  int n;
  vertex v;
};
```

I use the following code to iterate through the list and print all the members:

```
  vector<finalVertex> finalVertices;
  vector<finalVertex>::iterator ve;

  for ( ve = finalVertices.begin(); ve < finalVertices.end(); ve++ )
    {
      out << *(ve).v.x << *(ve).v.y << *(ve).v.z << endl;
    }
```

I receive the following code of error:

> main.cpp:651: error: 'class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >' has no
>   member named 'v'

What is the syntactically correct way of accessing the elements of the set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence: write `(*ve).v.x` or simpler, `ve->v.x`.

Apart from that, I would advise you to override `operator <<` for your `vertex` structure to make your code vastly more readable:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, vertex const& value) {
    return out << value.x << " " << value.y << " " << value.z;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
for ( ve = finalVertices.begin(); ve != finalVertices.end(); ve++ )
    out << ve->v << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is:

```
ve->v.x
```

What you can also do is:

```
(*ve).v.x
```

but it sucks. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
out << *(ve).v.x << *(ve).v.y << *(ve).v.z << endl;
```

Your `*(ve).v.x` is equivalent to `*((ve).v.x)`. You probably want:

```
out << (*ve).v.x << (*ve).v.y << (*ve).v.z << endl;
```

Or:

```
out << ve->v.x << ve->v.y << ve->v.z << endl;
```

Also, your loop isn't as efficient as it could be.  Calling `end()` every iteration isn't needed, and post-increment can be a lot heavier with iterators than plain pointers/integers so you should get used to using pre-increment when possible:

```
for ( ve = finalVertices.begin(), end = finalVertices.end(); ve != end; ++ve )
```

Comment: Well, you know, end() is inlined with optimized build and should not involve any calculation with a typical container, so ...

Comment: @ypnos: probably, yes. but there are plenty of atypical containers out there.

Answer (score 2):

Move your dereference to inside the parens, like so:

```
out << (*ve).v.x << (*ve).v.y << (*ve).v.z << endl;
```

I'd also suggest changing `ve < finalVertices.end();` to `ve != finalVertices.end();`.

Answer (score 2):

```
        for ( ve = finalVertices.begin(); ve != finalVertices.end(); ++ve )
        {
            ve->v.x;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not write 
**ve < finalVertices.end()**
you must write
**ve != finalVertices.end()**